# rails 5 enum where "like"

Tags: activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to query an activerecord model enum and use the like operator in the where method, and it just doesnt work. Is there some trick to allow me to query an enum this way? Works fine on regular columns. Here it is in the console.

Regular string column (title) works as shown below

```
irb(main):092:0> Proposal.select(:id,:department,:status).where('title like "test%"')
Proposal Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "proposals"."id", "proposals"."department", "proposals"."status" FROM "proposals" WHERE (title like "test%") LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Proposal id: 7, department: 1, status: "In Progress">, #<Proposal id: 61, department: 2, status: "Won">]>
```

However, trying it on an enum, gives no results.

```
irb(main):094:0> Proposal.select(:department,:status).where('status like "Wo%"')
Proposal Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "proposals"."department", "proposals"."status" FROM "proposals" WHERE (status like "Wo%") LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Any idea why I can't use like operator on enum? I'm trying to use this to filter a view with datatables.net server side processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum stores data as integer like 0,1,2,3... Then rails map number to enum value defined in model. That is the reason why you doesn't get result

Comment: So Proposal.where("title like 'Coat%'") works on a string column, but not a enum because the integer value for the enum is in the db, and the .where method doesnt have any knowledge of the enum? Thats rather limiting. Guess the only choice is to move it to a model rather than enum

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `like` in your case. When you define enum you have list of few strings/symbols and you can build query in this way `Proposal.where(title: %i[title1 title2 title3])`.  If title is just custom string then do not use enum.

Comment: I'm showing the status on an index view of the Proposals, and with datatables.net I can do a partial search on any field (except the enum field). It would be nice to be able to type pend and have it filter for just pending proposals. Since I'm using server side processing on the datatables, I have to do my searching as "where name like '%pend%' or status like '%pend%', etc

Comment: Now I understand. So you can use normal string is this case, but in my opinion better is match 'search word' to status in ruby. Then query database by matched status/statuses. You can get all of statuses by `Proposal.statuses`

Comment: Not sure I fully get what you saying, but I think your suggesting I match the partial status to the statuses first, then use that info in the where clause, if it matched one