# Search query not taking the input given - ActiveRecord enum LIKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to implement simple search on rails app.

**productions_controller**

```
def filter
    if params[:filter]
      @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{Production.statuses[params[:filter]]}%")
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
end
```

There is a list of records on the index page. I am implementing search/filter on those list based on `status` which are in enum datatype.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag [:filter, :productions], :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :status => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When I entered a keyword `pre` in the text field, this is what happens in the logs

```
Processing by ProductionsController#filter as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>"pre", "commit"=>"Filter"}
  Rendering productions/filter.html.erb within layouts/application
  Production Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "productions".* FROM "productions" WHERE (productions.status like '%%')
  Rendered productions/filter.html.erb
```

It looks like it's taking the entered keyword but not while querying. May be I'm wrong. Could somebody help me here ?

Adding **production.rb** as requested

```
class Production < ApplicationRecord    
  enum status:{
    Preproduction:1,
    Postproduction: 2,
    Completed:3
  } 
end
```

Comment: What is `Production.statuses` ? Can you post the `Production` model code?

Comment: @GokulM In order to query status based on the string names assigned instead of numbers I had to use that. I added the model please check

Comment: Production.statuses
 => {"Preproduction"=>1, "Postproduction"=>2, "Completed"=>3}

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't use enums with LIKE statements like you are doing. It would only work if you queried it like this.

```
@productions = Production.where(status: "Preproduction")
```

Here is another post with a similar issue:
[rails 5 enum where "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079147/rails-5-enum-where-like)

I would recommend you change

```
<%= form_tag [:filter, :productions], :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :status => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

to this

```
<%= form_tag [:filter, :productions], :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag :filter, options_for_select(Production.statuses) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :status => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the status are stored as integers you can use the below method to filter the `productions` based on the status value.

```
def filter
    filtered_statuses = params[:filter].present? ? Production.statuses.select{|k, v| k.to_s.include?(params[:filter])} : nil

    if filtered_statuses
      @productions = Production.where(status: filtered_statuses.values)
    elsif params[:filter].present?
      @productions = []  # To return empty if no search filter matches production statuses
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass only `params[:filter]`
like these

```
def filter
    if params[:filter]
      @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{params[:filter]}%")
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
end
```

Comment: If I do this then I am forced to enter integer status in the text field like `1` or `2`. But I want to be able to give the names that I gave like `Preproduction` in production.rb model.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `pre` as filter and you do not have any status with pre and that is the same reason you are unable to find any data.
However you still need to update code a bit

```
     @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{Production.statuses[params[:filter].capitalize]}%")
```

Problem is not with code as if the filter word doesn't matches any key it will give you `nil` as you are already doing string interpolation so it will become blank and finally you are trying to access `"%%"` which looks like your enum is not working. If you are providing filter for enum provide select filed instead of input and directly filter data based on status as mentioned in answers.
Hope this might help

Comment: Your solution works too. Yeah like you I am supposed to enter complete keyword. Currently I am using a text field to enter the keywords. Since the status keywords are fixed, is there a way to make them appear in a drop down to select ? How do I do that ?

Comment: `select_tag(:status, options_for_select(Production.statuses.map{|h, k| [h, k]}))` or `options_for_select(Production.statuses)`  This might work.